# How can i count post from my post type taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, count

How can i get the count for published post from my custom post type , from my taxonomy.

I have Custom Post Type : trailers,  Taxonomy : trailere-noi

```
<?php 

$items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'trailers',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'taxonomy'    => 'trailere-noi',
    ));

$count =  count( $posts );
echo $count;


?>
```

I use this code it conunt for how posts are display.. how can get the count for all posts in that taxonomy?

---

Response:

```
<?php 
$related_posts = get_field( 'subtitrare_film' );
$count =  count( $related_posts );
echo $count;
?>
```

Subtitrare_film - is the relathionship field (INFO :http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/relationship/)
This code Retrive me the field counting number, but the problem is: if there is nothing atached to that Custom Field ( Relationship fild) it retrive me number 1 , i want to display 0 ( if there is nothing atachhed.)

Comment: ... you need to be counting `$items` not `$posts`. 

    `$count = count($items);`

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
$items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'trailers',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'taxonomy'    => 'trailere-noi',
    ));

echo $posts->post_count;
```

Comment: nope, is not retriving...

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i see another thing in your code, your count() function is counting something that does't exists, the variable $posts, so please try with $items->post_count;

another option is :

```
global $wp_query
$items = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'trailers',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'taxonomy'    => 'trailere-noi',
    ));

echo $wp_query->found_posts
```

$wp_query should return the last query and since get_posts() works with wp_query this solution should work